# XmlHttpRequest returning empty response

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-9

Asking for a Zip file, in javascript works in all browsers. But on IE9 requests is readyState 4 and status Ok.

But request.response is undefined. request.responseBody is also undefined.

Someone knows why this could be happening?.

Edit: Is responding with responseXML, but i need an arraybuffer type of response.

Answer (score 0):

IE < 10 does not support `XMLHttpRequest.response` and I've never even heard of `XMLHttpRequest.responseBody`.